# How to disable automatic title inclusion in org-mode HTML export?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have an org-mode project with many small org files that I'd like to export to HTML. I have not set `#+TITLE` in many files as they do not have proper titles. I find on export that the partial first sentence is exported as the document's title.

For instance, an org document like so:

```
This is a short file.

Mary had a little lamb, etc.
```

Will be exported to have the following HTML:

```
*snip*
<div id="content">
<h1 class="title">This is a short file.</h1>


<p>Mary had a little lamb, etc.</p>
*snip*
```

I would prefer to see both sentences in the above file be marked as paragraphs. How can I disable the automatic divination of titles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take a look on the code of `org-export-region-as-html` you will see the following fragment

```
(title (or (and subtree-p (org-export-get-title-from-subtree))
           (plist-get opt-plist :title)
           (and (not
                 (plist-get opt-plist :skip-before-1st-heading))
                (org-export-grab-title-from-buffer))
           (and buffer-file-name
                (file-name-sans-extension
                 (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name)))
           "UNTITLED"))
```

A function `org-export-grab-title-from-buffer` is called if no title is defined. You can disable this function by *advising* it

```
(defadvice org-export-grab-title-from-buffer (around org-export-grab-title-from-buffer-disable activate))
```

Comment: Could you link to documentation describing this facility? How did you know of this?

Comment: @troutwine I think he just read the source.. actually defadvice is not a setting provided by Org, its rathar created by the user with lisp magic.

Comment: You may tell org mode that there is no title then it will not have a title. You don't need to hack on it.

Comment: This answer is no longer applicable: the function `org-export-grab-title-from-buffer` does not exist as of 2014-05-22, so any modern version of org (9.x.x) does not have it.

Answer (score 8):

To avoid the first line becoming the title you can set an empty title:

```
#+Title:

This is a short file.

Mary had a little lamb, etc.
```

Comment: This also disables the `<title>`